# Document Core Pack fetch

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, fetchxml

can anyone give me ***an Example of fetch Condition*** that i can used for the Document Core Pack fetchxml
i use the DCP for a dynamics crm Template.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use advanced find and export Fetch xml and use that.